# Split a file name and only take one part for use

Tags: php, regex, string-matching

I have a $value such as 22214-HAV.jpg or 22214 HAV.jpg (notice no dash)

I want to run a quick function to pull only the number from filename.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A quick solution, which make use of PHPs type juggling

```
$number = (int) $filename;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
preg_match('/^\d+/' ,'22214-HAV.jpg', $matches);
var_dump($matches[0]);
```

Observations:

1. This will only match numbers starting exactly from the beginning. Any position can be allowed by removing `^`.
2. This will match any sequence of digits and not actual numbers. Numbers can be restricted by using `([1-9]\d*|0)` in place of `\d+`.
3. If no match is found `$matches[0]` will be `null` and not an empty string.

Further reading:

1. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php
2. http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use explode for this

```
   //for '-'
            list($reqval)=explode('-', $value); 
    //for space
            list($reqval)=explode(' ', $value); 


        echo $reqval
```